# Default position and size for new Textmate windows

Tags: textmate

In TextMate, is it possible to define the default size and position for new windows? How?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the default window size by running these commands in the terminal.

**For Textmate 1:**

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakDocumentWindowFrame -string "{{0, 0}, {1440, 900}}"
```

**For Textmate 2:**

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview DocumentControllerWindowFrame -string "{{0, 0}, {1440, 900}}"
```

For both, `{0, 0}` represents *{left position, bottom position)*, and `{1440, 900}` represents *{width, height}*. These values will probably be overwritten by TextMate when it decides to redefine the default window size (as determined by the size of the last closed window (?)).

Comment: tried both commands, but when I launch Texmate app, it still opens with a small-sized window

Answer (score 0):

It only remembers the last open window's position and size. If you need a specific size and position, I would write an applescript.

Answer (score 0):

Open `~/Library/Preferences/com.macromates.textmate.plist` and look for the entry named `OakDocumentWindowFrame`. There you can adjust the width and height for new windows.